# Proper way to handle a continuous TCPClient ReadAsync Networkstream exception

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, tcpclient, networkstream

I have an application that runs a background thread which communicates to multiple devices.  The devices send me data based off an external trigger that I do not control.  I have to wait for the devices to send me data and operate on them.  If an exception occurs, I need to display that on the UI.

I am attempting to continuously read data over the network stream.  When data comes, I need to raise it as an event and then start reading again.  I need to be able to handle if an exception is thrown such as the device being disconnected.

At the base I have a network stream reading asynchronously

```
    public Task<string> ReadLinesAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        _readBuffer = new byte[c_readBufferSize];
        // start asynchronously reading data
        Task<int> streamTask = _networkstream.ReadAsync(_readBuffer, 0, c_readBufferSize, token);
        // wait for data to arrive
        Task<String> resultTask = streamTask.ContinueWith<String>(antecedent =>
        {
            // resize the result to the size of the data that was returned
            Array.Resize(ref _readBuffer, streamTask.Result);
            // convert returned data to string
            var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_readBuffer);
            return result; // return read string
        }, token);
        return resultTask;
    }
```

So the way I am trying to do this is on start up, I start a thread that is reading by running the Start() method.  But when an exception is thrown it kills my program even though I put some error trapping around it.  I have been attempting to trap it at different places just to see what happens but I have not been able to figure out the proper way to do this so that I can raise the error to the UI without bombing out my application.

```
async public override void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            await _client.ReadLinesAsync(_cts.Token).ContinueWith(ReadLinesOnContinuationAction, _cts.Token);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            ae.Handle((exc) =>
            {
                if (exc is TaskCanceledException)
                {

                    _log.Info(Name + " - Start() - AggregateException"
                        + " - OperationCanceledException Handled.");
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _log.Error(Name + " - Start() - AggregateException - Unhandled Exception"
                    + exc.Message, ae);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error(Name + " - Start() - unhandled exception.", ex);
        }
    }
async private void ReadLinesOnContinuationAction(Task<String> text)
    {
        try
        {
            DataHasBeenReceived = true;
            IsConnected = true;
            _readLines.Append(text.Result);
            if (OnLineRead != null) OnLineRead(Name, _readLines.ToString());
            _readLines.Clear();
            await _client.ReadLinesAsync(_cts.Token).ContinueWith(ReadLinesOnContinuationAction, _cts.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _log.Error(Name + " - ReadLinesOnContinuationAction()");
        }
    }
```

The debugger usually stops on the line:
   `_readLines.Append(text.Result);`
I tried putting this within a check for the text.IsFaulted flag but then I bombed out on the .ContinueWith.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I need to fix this so that I can properly catch the error and raise the even to the UI?  This code has all kinds of bad smells to it but I am learning this as I go along.  Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bombed out with which ContinueWith? You have at least two that I see.

Personally, I would not mix async/await with ContinueWith. The await is already giving you a convenient way to do a ContinueWith, so just use that. For example:

```
public async Task<string> ReadLinesAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    _readBuffer = new byte[c_readBufferSize];
    // start asynchronously reading data
    int readResult = await _networkstream.ReadAsync(_readBuffer, 0, c_readBufferSize, token);
    // after data arrives...

    // resize the result to the size of the data that was returned
    Array.Resize(ref _readBuffer, streamTask.Result);
    // convert returned data to string
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_readBuffer);
}

async public override void Start()
{
    try
    {
        string text = await _client.ReadLinesAsync(_cts.Token);
        await ReadLinesOnContinuationAction(text);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        ae.Handle((exc) =>
        {
            if (exc is TaskCanceledException)
            {

                _log.Info(Name + " - Start() - AggregateException"
                    + " - OperationCanceledException Handled.");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Error(Name + " - Start() - AggregateException - Unhandled Exception"
                + exc.Message, ae);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error(Name + " - Start() - unhandled exception.", ex);
    }
}

async private Task ReadLinesOnContinuationAction(Task<String> text)
{
    try
    {
        DataHasBeenReceived = true;
        IsConnected = true;
        _readLines.Append(text.Result);
        if (OnLineRead != null) OnLineRead(Name, _readLines.ToString());
        _readLines.Clear();
        string text = await _client.ReadLinesAsync(_cts.Token);
        await ReadLinesOnContinuationAction(text);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        _log.Error(Name + " - ReadLinesOnContinuationAction()");
    }
}
```

Or something like that. The above is obviously not compiled and might require a little bit of massaging to get right. But hopefully the general idea is clear enough.

Comment: It was on the ReadLinesOnContinuationAction continue with. Thanks for the reply. I didn't even think about that. I will give that a try this morning and let you know.

Comment: Shouldn't calling ReadLinesOnContinuationAction() inside ReadLinesOnContinuationAction() will throw a StackOverflowException at some point ?
I think you should do this in a while(!_cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) loop

Comment: @LuftWaffle: _"will throw a StackOverflowException"_ -- no, it won't. The call to `ReadLinesAsync()` will eventually yield the thread (i.e. as soon as there is not data immediately available). Once that happens, that interrupts the recursion, preventing overflow. That said, if you are concerned about the possibility of never running out of data to read (and if so, async operations may not be appropriate anyway), you can pass a counter to the method to track call stack depth and `await Task.Yield()` after enough calls, to ensure the thread is yielded.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know Task.Yield do that. You said async operations may not be appropriate for continuous read (when listening for data for example). What may be appropriate then ?

Comment: @LuftWaffle: if you know that data will always be present when you attempt to read, and thus the async operation will always complete synchronously, and thus the thread will never yield back to the caller, you might as well dedicate an explicit thread to the operation. This will avoid consuming a thread pool thread in the case where you started the operation in a thread pool thread, and will avoid blocking a thread with a synchronization context (e.g. the main UI thread in a GUI program) in the case where you started the operation in such a thread. Avoiding either of those would be good.